# No hyperlink borders for any kind of glossaries entries but still hyperreferred

Tags: hyperref, glossaries

I would like to have the default behaviour of hyperref for all links excepted the ones from glossaries: for them, they should be still links but without borders

I started playing with `\hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = white...` options but when I saw that \cref was also impacted by link* options I tried more specific commands:

```
\renewcommand*{\glstextformat}[1]{\hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = white}{#1}\hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = black}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = white}\glshyperlink[\glsgenentryfmt]{\glslabel}\hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = black}%
}
```

But those renewcommands doesn't do anything

UPDATE

I was using an external files for glossaries entries and in fact those was acronyms not regular entries. So my solution and the one gave was not working due to the mix of acronyms and regular entries.
I finally came with a solution, which -I hope- is correct; so if you could review it I would greatly appreciate Thx:

```
\usepackage[linkbordercolor={black}]{hyperref}
```

[...]

```
\defglsentryfmt{% 
\ifglsacronym%
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = white}\glshyperlink[\glsgenacfmt]{\glslabel} %
\else
\hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = white}\glshyperlink[\glsgenentryfmt]{\glslabel}%
\fi
}
```

Comment: let me share my discovery: \loadglsentries blows up the renewcommands

Comment: @flop25: No, it does not, unless you do something weird, but you did not really provide a compilable document :-(

Comment: @flop25: I asked you to provide a compilable document, not just fragments. I won't check fragments only

Comment: my solution works so if you don't want to check if there is no harmful side-effects that's mainly for future readers. Thx anyway for your time

Answer (score 2):

This works out of the box for me -- the grouping of `\glsentryfmt` does not require a reset of the linkborder color after the `\glslabel` has been used.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linkbordercolor={black}]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={A foobar}
}

\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = white}\glshyperlink[\glsgenentryfmt]{\glslabel}%
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\section{Foo} \label{FOO}

In \Cref{FOO} we saw that \gls{foo}

\clearpage

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** A version that uses `\thepagecolor` (for the rare case of non-white page colours)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage[linkbordercolor={black}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{foo}{%
  name={Foo},
  description={A foobar}
}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\glsentryfmt}{%
  \hypersetup{linkbordercolor  = \thepagecolor}\glshyperlink[\glsgenentryfmt]{\glslabel}%
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow}

\section{Foo} \label{FOO}

In \Cref{FOO} we saw that \gls{foo}

\clearpage

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Comment: try with \loadglsentries{foo} and let the fun begin

Comment: @flop25: Well, what do you mean? It works with `\loadglsentries{filename}` of course as well.

Comment: I dig much deeper and found out the cause and a probable solution Could you check plz? Thx for your answers

Comment: also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296552/99343 for another solution